# Prove that there are at least $1000$ beautiful numbers each of which is divisible by $37$

Tags: number-theory

Here is the problem:

> A nine-digit integer is called *beautiful* if all of its digits are different. Prove that there exist at least $1000$ beautiful numbers, each of which is divisible by $37.$

Here is what I did:

Let $n$ be a beautiful number which is divisible by $37$
,we have $$n=\overline{a_9a_8\ldots a_1}$$
Otherwise , $10^3\equiv 1 \mod 37$

so $$10^2(a_9+a_6+a_3)+10(a_8+a_5+a_2)+(a_7+a_4+a_1)\equiv 0 \mod 37$$

$$-11(a_9+a_6+a_3)+10(a_8+a_5+a_2)+(a_7+a_4+a_1)\equiv 0 \mod 37$$
$$10(a_8+a_5+a_2-a_9-a_6-a_3)+(a_7+a_4+a_1-a_9-a_6-a_3)\equiv 0 \mod 37$$
we see that if $a_8+a_5+a_2=a_9+a_6+a_3=
a_7+a_4+a_1$ we would be done

Otherwise $1+9+5=3+4+8=6+7+2$
so $a_8$ has 9 choices  , $a_5$ has $2$ , $a_9$ has 6 , $a_6$ has $2$ , $a_7$ has $3$ , $a_4$ has $2$

So there are at least $1296$ beautiful numbers each of which is divisible by $37$

I just want to know if this is right.

Comment: Can you link to a source of this (nice) problem?

Comment: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/dzmitry/TT_problems/TT40JO.pdf

Comment: In the two places where you say "Otherwise," I think you mean "Because," and where you say "I just want if this is right," I'm pretty sure you mean "I just want *to know* if this is right." But where you say "unless don't," do you want a correct solution if yours is not, or do you just want to know if yours is correct?

Comment: thanks , i don't want a correct solution , i just want to know if this is right